# Trying to create a SQL command to re-format and combine 3 table values

Tags: mysql, sql, parsing

I have a single database table which contains the three columns seen below:

[image]

I would like to know how I can construct a SQL command (or series of SQL commands) to break down the three values and then update a new column with the combination.

As you can see in the screenshot, the billing details are currently set in the following format:

```
cb_fplanexpdate = 2026/09/07 (YYYY/MM/DD)
cb_cardtype = Discover Credit Card
cb_cardnumbers = XXXX XXXX XXXX 4242
```

In this example, I would need to create a new value for the `account_billing_key` column.  The format for `account_billing_key` column would be:

```
CC;1234;MM/YY
```

So, that is the credit card abbreviation, followed by a semi-colon, then the last four digits from the card, followed by a semi-colon and finally the month and last two digits of the year.  So, in this screenshot example we would see:

```
DS;4242;09/26
```

I have done this type of extraction with PHP, but am unsure about how to parse information with SQL.

Comment: Correct your tags: mysql and sql server are different.

Comment: Also learn about db normalization.

Comment: What database, MySQL, SQL Server, you have both in your Tags.

Comment: Are you storing full card numbers or just the last four digits?

Comment: What is credit card abbreviation ? how can you decide “Discover Credit Card” convert to  “DS”?

Comment: tags are updated, this is mysql

Answer (score 2):

As you didn't specify between SQL Server and MySQL here's both:

**SQL Server:**

```
SELECT CASE WHEN cb_cardtype = 'Discover Credit Card' THEN 'DS' 
            WHEN cb_cardtype = 'Some other card' THEN 'SO' 
       END + ';'
       + RIGHT(cb_cardnumbers,4) + ';'
       + DATEPART(mm,cb_planexpdate) + '/' + DATEPART(dd,cb_planexpdate)
       AS account_billing_key 
FROM CreditCard_Table
```

**MySQL**

```
SELECT CONCAT(CASE WHEN cb_cardtype = 'Discover Credit Card' THEN 'DS' 
            WHEN cb_cardtype = 'Some other card' THEN 'SO' 
       END, ';',
       RIGHT(cb_cardnumbers,4), ';',
       LPAD(MONTH(cb_planexpdate), 2, '0'), '/', LPAD(DAY(cb_planexpdate), 2, '0'))
       AS account_billing_key 
FROM CreditCard_Table
```

You will have to update the `CASE` statement to perform whatever logic you use to determine the card type.

Comment: Or add a field like I did to the table.  Or add a table of card types to the ERD.  Either way, the data is not in the schema.

Comment: I tried this, but I get `#1305 - FUNCTION my_table.DATEPART does not exist`  Prior to that I had to add back ticks to `[Your_table]` in order to clear out a sytnax error... so `'Your_table'`.  Was that correct?

Comment: You need to replace the value `Your_Table` with the name of the table you are using. You never specified if this was MYSQL or SQL SERVER, I'm guessing it's MYSQL if you are seeing the DATEPART does not exist error. Will try to provide a MYSQL version

Comment: @Tanner thanks for the update.  Yes, it is MySQL.  I have attempted your MySQL code and I am able to run the statement and get the `account_billing_key`.  The only problem is that it is not building the value correctly.  Right now running your statement gives the value `4258`.  I am still working with it, but I am unsure as to why the value `4258` is created.

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but the delimiter is set as a semi-colon.  Since I am using the semi-colon to build the value would this be an issue?

Comment: @Tanner okay I figured out why I am getting `4258`.  MySQL is taking the `+` and adding the values.  So, `4242` plus `09` plus `07` gives `4258`.  So, it looks like I need to use `CONCAT()` to put the values next to each other.

Comment: I finally figured it out.  You can see my answer below.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Presto have updated the SQL to reflect the `CONCAT` syntax for string joining in MySQL as written in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could try the following simple sql code, it works as expected, but the fields can't change the layout:

```
UPDATE *tbl_name* SET 
    account_billing_key=CONCAT(
        SUBSTRING(cb_cardtype    , 1, 2),';',
        SUBSTRING(cb_cardnumbers ,16, 4),';',
        SUBSTRING(cb_fplanexpdate, 6, 2),'/',
        SUBSTRING(cb_fplanexpdate, 3, 2)
        )
```

Comment: You need card abbreviation, not card type.

Answer (score 0):

This solution adds a abbreviation column to the table.  The second select statement gives you the answer.

You could also use a calculated field (persistent) if you are doing this a-lot.  This would physically store the results.

There is not checking for invalid data like NULLS.  I leave that up to you.

**Sample code**

```
-- Just playing
use tempdb
go

-- Sample table (add abreviation col)
create table cards
(
cb_fplanexpdate datetime,
cb_cardtype nvarchar(50),
cb_cardnumbers nvarchar(25),
cb_cardabrv nvarchar(2)
)
go

-- Some data
insert into cards values
('20260907', 'Discover Credit Card', 'XXXX XXXX XXXX 4242', 'DS')
go

-- Show all data
select * from cards
go

-- Show output data
select 
    cb_cardabrv + ';' +
    substring(cb_cardnumbers, len(cb_cardnumbers) - 3, 4) + ';' +
    substring(convert(char(10), cb_fplanexpdate, 103), 4, 3) + 
    substring(convert(char(10), cb_fplanexpdate, 103), 9, 2) + 
    ';' as my_string
from cards
go
```

**Sample Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, Tanner's answer got me 90% of the way, but I had to change the `+` to `CONCAT` in order to build the statement as I needed it.  So, here is the final statement:

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(
CASE WHEN cb_cardtype = 'Discover Credit Card' THEN 'DS' 
WHEN cb_cardtype = 'Some other card' THEN 'SO' END, 
';', 
RIGHT(cb_cardnumbers,4), 
';', 
LPAD(MONTH(cb_fplanexpdate), 2, '0'),
'/', 
LPAD(YEAR(cb_fplanexpdate), 2, '0')
) AS account_billing_key 
FROM my_table
```